# ASP.NET MVC & C# : better Dollars and Cents data entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to better control the user experience of `Html.TextBoxFor`?

I currently have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalDue,
    new { @id = "TotalDue", @class = "decimal_input", @dir = "rtl" })
```

And a model of:

```
public decimal TotalDue { get; set; }
```

When a user comes to that field, if a 0 is displayed and the user begins to type his/her dollar amount, the leading zero stays there.  When the user leaves the field, the amount is not formatted.

Ideally, I would like the user to come to the field and if they typed 123456.78 and then pressed TAB to the next field, it would display 123,456.78.  If they type 123456, it would display 123,456.00.  It would be best if it formatted as they typed, although I could live with just making the field pretty when they leave the field.

I have experimented with `Html.EditorFor`, but haven't found the right combination. I am open to using that or a "helper" of some sort. I would like the user to have the same experience as found in PDF forms, or something close to it.

Comment: If you use jQuery then this is the sort of thing you need https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask.  This one uses only JS: https://imask.js.org/.  On a web page this is something you would do in JavaScript rather than C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: [imask.js](https://imask.js.org/).  I've done a jsfiddle to demonstrate [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bfren/t379bv8j/7/), and a .NET fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i0YVyF).

Include `<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>` on your page and then this script:

```js
var totalDueMask = IMask(
  document.getElementById('TotalDue'),
  {
    mask: '$num',
    blocks: {
      num: {
        mask: Number,
        radix: '.',
        thousandsSeparator: ','
      }
    }
  }
);
```

I've formatted it for USD but you can adjust the settings to suit - all the options are documented on the IMask site.

Comment: This works great in the way that you structured it.  I already have most of this project written using (at)Html.TextBoxFor to get my values.  It would be a big re-write to change to the <input type="text" id="TotalDue"/> method that you provided.  Is there any way to do it with (at)Html.TextBoxFor or (at)Html.EditorFor?

Comment: Great.  Yes - whatever @Html.TextBoxFor outputs as the id for the element, put that in `document.getElementById(xxxx)`, and it should then work.  From your code sample it looks to me like that should be 'TotalDue'.  (Unfortunately JSFiddle doesn't support Razor methods so I had to put the text box in manually.)

Comment: I would have thought that too, but the following does not work:  

<script>
        var TotalDueMask = IMask(document.getElementById('TotalDue'),
            { mask: '$num', blocks: { num: { mask: Number, radix: '.', thousandsSeparator: ',' } } });
</script>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TotalDue, new { @id = "TotalDue"})

Comment: Hmm, when I try it, the ID is exactly as it should be.  So you're going to have to (1) right click and view source then to find out what .NET is generating as the ID for the text box.  Also, (2) the JS code should be inserted at the bottom of the page / after @Html.TextBoxFor(), to ensure it executes *after* the page is built.  It may be that it's executing before the page HTML has been built.  Finally (3) double check you have <script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script> in the <head/> section of the page.

Comment: I've done a few more tests and I'm fairly sure the issue is with the positioning of the JS code rather than the ID attribute, which when I run some Razor, the ID is set as intended, i.e. according to what is in `new { @id = xxx }`.

Comment: I've added a .NET fiddle here to show this working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/i0YVyF

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, you are right.  The <script> for the mask has to go AFTER the (at)HTML...  For my purposes, I removed the $ in $num and I made the field right justified with (at)dir="rtl".  One strange quirk:  When entering 300000 and pressing tab, it doesn't convert it to 300,000.00.  Same is true for 300000.10, it drops the final zero.  Any ideas?  This is already a big improvement from what I had.  Many thanks!

Comment: Basically I want the mask to be "N2"

Comment: For the zeroes, you want to add normalizeZeros: false, and padFractionalZeros: true - I've updated the .NET Fiddle to show.  I'm not sure what's happening with the thousands separator as I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: How are you getting on with this?

Comment: Perfect solution!  Thanks!  Sorry if what I said above was confusing.  No problems with the thousands separator.

Comment: I have to say, whoever said this was easier than COBOL never had the opportunity to do it on a DEC VAX with FMS forms.  We had built a small, callable routine that let a user edit his entry by parsing the entry.  So the computer would first display [     45.12] and then the user could type [69.78] on the left part of the box.  They would use a space to separate the numbers.  Then our routine would re-parse the entry to make 69.78 override 45.12

Comment: Lol - yes new is not always better! Glad I could help.